# How to make email field not required in comments?

Tags: comments

I need to make email field not required in comments, is it possible ?

I know about this option: https://prnt.sc/vyt3s9
But then Name field will not be required to

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this filter. Removing the required field option from the form.

`add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','modify_comment_fields');`

Comment: Thank you, it is working!